# Launch MS Edge on Linux, directly opening Progressive Web App

Tags: linux, microsoft-edge, progressive-web-app

The official Microsoft Teams client for Linux being in a constant downturn, it seems to have gone essentially unmainted, with a growing number of meetings simply not working for participants.

The web client in firefox and chromium remains problematic with respect to displaying foreign screen shares. Thus, I'm switching over to running MS Teams as [progressive web app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app) (PWA) in Microsoft Edge (stable, Linux x86_64, installed via RPM on Fedora 37), where all base functions work on Linux.

I was trivially able to "install" Teams as app from the Edge burger menu.

However,

**how** do I launch msedge to directly open the PWA? I don't want to have to go through the menu to open the teams in a new window. I use Edge for literally nothing else.

Comment: Once you've got the teams pwa installed, you might be able to ask it to create a desktop shortcut in edge://apps, and either use that or steal the url from there. I don't have a linux machine handy, but the nt equivalent is `msedge_proxy.exe --app-id=[long unique id] --app-url=https://teams.microsoft.com/`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale that looks to be a viable answer. Do you want to post it as answer, to let me edit the answer to extend it to Linux? That way, I get an answer to mark my question answered, and you get the 150 rep bounty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've got the Microsoft Teams PWA installed, you might be able to ask it to create a desktop shortcut.

Go through the `…` menu -> "Apps" -> "Manage Apps"; and in the `edge://apps` tab that opens, on the Teams PWA, go the `…` menu,

[image: entry in edge://apps, context menu on "..." opened]

select "Create shortcut…", and there, select only pinning to "Desktop"

[image: Pin to Desktop modal]

Afterwards, you will find a file in your Desktop directory (and if you're like many users that don't use a window manager with an MS Windows-Style desktop directory, you can `cd "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"`).

That directory contains a freshly created file `mstedge-${app_id}-Default.desktop`, where `${app_id}` is a random-looking alphabetic string.

Looking at its content,

```ini
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Microsoft Teams
Exec=/opt/microsoft/msedge/microsoft-edge --profile-directory=Default --app-id=cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo "--app-url=https://teams.microsoft.com/?clientType=pwa"
Icon=msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default
StartupWMClass=crx__cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo
```

**The `Exec` line is what you're looking for!**

```
/opt/microsoft/msedge/microsoft-edge \
    --profile-directory=Default \
    --app-id=cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo \
   "--app-url=https://teams.microsoft.com/?clientType=pwa"
```

On Windows, the equivalent you get is

```
msedge_proxy.exe --app-id=[long unique id] --app-url=https://teams.microsoft.com/
```

You can also install that to be included in your start menu; give it a category:

```shell
echo 'Categories=Network,VideoConference' >> msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop
```

Afterwards, it can be established as menu entry:

```shell
xdg-desktop-menu install msedge-cifhbcnohmdccbgoicgdjpfamggdegmo-Default.desktop
```